# RestAssured, unable to pass objects of POJO for nested json in io.RestAssured

Tags: json, pojo, rest-assured

Here is my Jsonbody that I want to post, and I created POJO for child node such as Phone, fax along with the Info (parent node). I can't get the child node elements, the info elements work just fine.

```
info
        {
          "Name": "Auto Test",
          "addressLine1": "4399 Apple ln",
          "city": "BlahWonders",
          "state": "GA",
          "zipCode": "30555",
          "phone": {
            "countryCode": "1",
            "areaCode": "678",
            "dialNumber": "3196864"
          },
          "fax": {
            "countryCode": "1",
            "nationalPrefix": "1",
            "areaCode": "333",
            "dialNumber": "3333333"
          },

    }
```

I created POJO class for the respecive classes Info, phone, fax. 
I created a new object for each setting the values in each class. ofcourse my Info class has the following:

```
private String name;
private String addressLine1;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zipCode;
private HashMap<String,Phone> phone;
private HashMap<String,Fax> fax;
Info info = new Info();
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        phone.setAreaCode("333");
        phone.setCountryCode("");
        phone.setDialNumber("666666");
        Fax fax = new Fax();
        fax.setAreaCode("555");
        fax.setCountryCode("usa");
        fax.setDialNumber("9999999");
        HashMap<String,Fax> faxMap= new HashMap<String,Fax>();
        faxMap.put("fax",fax);
        HashMap<String,Phone> phoneMap= new HashMap<String,Phone>();
        phoneMap.put("phone",phone);
        info.setFax(faxMap);
        info.setPhone(phoneMap);
.
.
.
.
```

RestAssured validation for post: I get 400

```
given().contentType("application/json").body(info).when().post("/info/add");
```

Can someone tell whats wrong with this? I tried the same in postman and it works. I get an error "Unrecognized property 'phone'

Comment: Hard to follow. Can you share few more details so that it is easy to understand what you are facing

Answer (score 0):

In your case phone and fax should not be HashMap but just plane objects. Following example will provide required output:

```
@Data //using lombok annotation to reduce code amount
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Phone {
    private String countryCode;
    private String areaCode;
    private String dialNumber;
}

@Data
public class Fax {
@AllArgsConstructor
    private String countryCode;
    private String nationalPrefix;
    private String areaCode;
    private String dialNumber;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Info {
    private String name;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private Phone phone;
    private Fax fax;
}

public void test() {
...
given()
        .when()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(new Info("Auto Test", "4399 Apple ln", "BlahWonders", GA", "30555", 
                     new Phone("1", "678", "3196864"), 
                     new Fax("1", "1", "333", "3333333")))
...
}
```

But in case of:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Info {
    private String name;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private Map<String, Phone> phones;
    private Map<String, Fax> faxes;
}
```

you will get:

```
{
  "name": "Auto Test",
  "addressLine1": "4399 Apple ln",
  "city": "BlahWonders",
  "state": "GA",
  "zipCode": "30555",
  "phones": {
    "phone": {
      "countryCode": "1",
      "areaCode": "678",
      "dialNumber": "3196864"
    }
  },
  "faxes": {
    "fax": {
      "countryCode": "1",
      "nationalPrefix": "1",
      "areaCode": "333",
      "dialNumber": "3333333"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks RocketRaccoon, I got it working chaging fax to another pojo, even hashmap would work, but there was a data validation error that actually failed the test.